# Unable to get dictionary object from Powerscript output executed from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I have executed below PowerScript script to create LetsEncrypt certificate using ACMESharp client in C# using PowerShell.

```
Import-Module ACMESharp
if (!(Get-ACMEVault)) 
{
    Initialize-ACMEVault 
}
New-ACMERegistration -Contacts test@xyz.com -AcceptTos

New-ACMEIdentifier -Dns test.xyz.com -Alias test.xyz.com_Identifier
Complete-ACMEChallenge test.xyz.com_Identifier -ChallengeType http-01 -Handler iis -HandlerParameters @{ WebSiteRef = 'test.xyz.com'}
Submit-ACMEChallenge test.xyz.com_Identifier -ChallengeType http-01
Update-ACMEIdentifier test.xyz.com_Identifier -ChallengeType http-01
Update-ACMEIdentifier test.xyz.com_Identifier
```

Once I executed the script, it has generated the valid certificate as below output.

```
IdentifierPart : test.xyz.com_Identifier
IdentifierType : dns
Identifier     : test.xyz.com
Uri            : https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/_uNCmvqY9cgUZItjK-VYvgUJu-Ucj5JUCjJb9Vw7tTQ
Status         : valid
Expires        : 10/16/2017 12:31:35 PM
Challenges     : {, iis, }
Combinations   : {1, 2, 0}
```

Now, I want to get the status certification registration which is valid in this case. I would like to get the status and based on that I would like to keep performing update operation till the time it is not success.

Comment: How did you try reading it till now?

Answer (score 0):

You can query for the local status using the following:

```
$status  = Get-ACMEIdentifier test.xyz.com_Identifier
$statusName = $status.Status
Write-Host "Current status is $statusName"
```

If you want to update your local records with what is actually in LetsEncrypt then use

`Update-ACMEIdentifier test.xyz.com_Identifier`

to update your local information